# How to solve this complex logarithm equation?

Tags: complex-analysis

> define $Log z := ln|z| + i Argz$
>
> and solve the equation
>
> $Log(z^2-1)=i \pi/2$, for all possible value

I've try that

let $w=z^2-1$and $Log\ w = i\pi/2$, then $|w|=1$and$Arg\ w=\pi/2$

let $ w =re^{i\theta}$,then $r=1$and $\theta=\pi/2+2k\pi$

then we know that $z^2 = 1+e^{i(\pi/2+2k\pi)}$

and I stuck here, how do I know what z is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

We have $\ln|z^2-1|=0\iff|z^2-1|=1$

Let $z=x+iy\implies(x^2-y^2-1)^2+(2xy)^2=1$

Now Arg$(z^2-1)=\arctan\dfrac{2xy}{x^2-y^2-1}=\dfrac\pi2$

From [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation), $x^2-y^2-1=0$ and $xy>0\implies 2xy=1$ as $(2xy)^2=1$

We can set $x=\sec A,y=\tan A$ where $0<A<\pi$ as $xy>0$

So, we have $2\sec A\tan A=1\iff2\sin A=\cos^2A=1-\sin^2A\iff\sin^2A+2\sin A-1=0$

$\implies\sin A=\dfrac{-2\pm2\sqrt2}2=-1\pm\sqrt2$

But $-1-\sqrt2<-1\implies \sin A=\sqrt2-1$

$$\dfrac{\tan A}{\sec A}=\sqrt2-1\iff\dfrac{\tan A}{\sqrt2-1}=\dfrac{\sec A}1=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{\sec^2A-\tan^2A}{1^2-(\sqrt2-1)^2}}=\pm\dfrac1{2(\sqrt2-1)}$$

Comment: Wish I know the mistake here

Comment: I cna't understand the last line,
secA=+-[(secA^2-tanA^2)/(1-(2^0.5-1)^2)]^0.5

Comment: @VitoChou, $$\dfrac ab=\dfrac cd=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2-c^2}{b^2-d^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea

since $z^2-1=e^{Log(z^2-1)}=e^{i\frac\pi2}=i$

so $z^2=1+i=\sqrt2e^{i\frac\pi4}$

therefore $z=\sqrt[4]2e^{i\frac\pi8},\ \sqrt[4]2e^{i\frac{9\pi}{8}}$